# Definite integral of nested trig functions giving bessel function

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, bessel-functions, trigonometric-integrals

I put the following integral into wolfram alpha to solve as a part of a larger project I'm working and got this very curious result

$ \int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos{(A \cos{(y - x)}}) dx = 2\pi J_0(A)$ for real A

Why is this true? Why does a Bessel function pop up here? The factor of $2\pi$ suggests some contour integration going on here but I'm having trouble seeing it

EDIT: missing a bracket should be cos(y-x) not cosy - x

Comment: No. You must have done something wrong. If nothing else specified, $A,y$ constants, then the integral will be a normal integral over cos phaseshifted over one period which is $0$ no matter which phase.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+2pi+of+cos%28A*cos%28y%29-x%29dx

Comment: See the formula (149) in https://www.nbi.dk/~polesen/borel/node15.html.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect a typo somewhere.

Let $$A \cos(y)-x=t\implies x=-t -A \cos(y)\implies dx=-dt$$ making
$$\int \cos{(A \cos{y - x}})\, dx = -\int \cos(t) \,dt=\sin(t) +C$$
 What is true is 
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos{(A \cos{y - x}})\, d\color{red}{y} = 2 \pi  \cos (x) J_0(|A|)$$

Comment: For real $A$, the absolute value is irrelevant because $J_0$ is an even function. For complex $A$, the use of absolute value seems incorrect. (Taking $a=i $ in WA gives an answer in terms of $I_0(1)$, not $J_0(1)$.)

Answer (score 0):

For real values of the parameters the integrated function 
$$
f(x,y;A)=\cos{(A \cos{(x - y)}})
$$
is $\pi$ periodic with respect to $x$. Therefore:
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(A \cos(x-y))dx=\int_{-y}^{-y+2\pi}\cos(A\cos t)dt
=2\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(A\sin t)dt=2\pi J_0(A),
$$
the last equality following from the [integral representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel's_integrals) of the Bessel function.